# How to set expandLevel on a data source using a theme?

Tags: xpages

I would like to set expandLevel to 1 for all my dominoView data sources.

Inspired by [this XSnippet by Tony McGuckin](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=set-dojoattributes-and-attrs-on-a-control-in-an-xpages-theme-file) I am looking for a way to set expandLevel using a theme.

Is this possible using a theme and how?

Answer (score 0):

I'll of course defer to Tony, but my impression is that themes are evaluated too late in the lifecycle to be able to impact this particular attribute value. Were that not the case, something akin to the following might theoretically be valid:

```
<control>
    <name>DataTable.ViewPanel</name>
    <property>
        <name>data</name>
        <complex type="xp_dominoView">
            <property>
                <name>expandLevel</name>
                <value>#{1}</value>
            </property>
        </complex>
    </property>
</control>
```

I suspect, however, that Declan would tell you that using a PhaseListener or ViewHandler to would be a more viable approach... and I'm inclined to agree. ;)

Comment: Tim, this doesn't quite do it. I have tried similar constructs.
In my case the data source is on the custom control itself and not on the DataTable.ViewPanel. I assume that using ViewRoot as control name should take care of that.
I'm still hoping for Tony (or someone else from the IBM XPages team) to comment with the right answer :-)

Comment: Actually, ViewRoot only applies to the true root of the component tree, not to the xp:view tag in a custom control.

Comment: I'd agree with Tim. The theme gets evaluated during the Render Response phase. But the expandLevel property of your datasource will need to be set earlier on in the lifecycle, when it's building the server-side map of the XPage, in order to know what content needs to be rendered.